# changing the Opacity of UIView by swipe

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I've seen some other apps that can change the brightness of the iPhone screen. I think that they just only place a UIView and set its backgroundColor to black, then whenever the user swipe on the screen the opacity changes depending on the swipe of the finger.

Can anyone help me how can I mimic that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add an overlay of a UIView (in black color) on top.

(If you have no user-dependent controls in your view (such as buttons, steppers, etc) then, this is ok. For example you just have a UITextView on UIView, then you can add the black UIView on top of UITextView)

**(at the top) black UIView --> UITextView --> UIView**

You can then control the alpha component of the black UIView using

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];

    for(int i=0; i<[touchesArray count]; i++) {
        UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touchesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:nil];

        //set the relationship between point and alpha. Maybe when x increases then alpha increases. You do the math.
    }
}
```

By the way, set black UIView's alpha from 0.0 up to 0.7 (remember, setting it to full 1.0 will set the screen to full black.)

Setting alpha:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [blackView setAlpha:alphaCounter];
} [UIView commitAnimations];
```